# Three.js - How can I fix the controls to work in relation to the last camera position?

Tags: javascript, three.js

A three.js scene has W,A,S,D and left and right arrow controls. The controls move the camera but only in a fixed direction in the scene instead of relative to the last camera position. The controls are the standard gaming wasd with W moving forward.
Check out the live codepen example: 
[https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eydRea](http://control%20error)

```
var keyboard = {};
    var player= {height:30, speed:10, turnSpeed:Math.PI*0.02};  if(keyboard[87]){ // W key
    camera.position.x -= Math.sin(camera.rotation.y) * player.speed;
    camera.position.z -= -Math.cos(camera.rotation.y) * player.speed;
}
if(keyboard[83]){ // S key
    camera.position.x += Math.sin(camera.rotation.y) * player.speed;
    camera.position.z += -Math.cos(camera.rotation.y) * player.speed;
}
if(keyboard[65]){ // A key
    camera.position.x += Math.sin(camera.rotation.y + Math.PI/2) * player.speed;
    camera.position.z += -Math.cos(camera.rotation.y + Math.PI/2) * player.speed;
}
if(keyboard[68]){ // D key
    camera.position.x += Math.sin(camera.rotation.y - Math.PI/2) * player.speed;
    camera.position.z += -Math.cos(camera.rotation.y - Math.PI/2) * player.speed;
}

if(keyboard[37]){ // left arrow key
    camera.rotation.y -= player.turnSpeed;
}
if(keyboard[39]){ // right arrow key
    camera.rotation.y += player.turnSpeed;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is to first get the direction where the camera is facing & translate the camera in that particular direction.Follow this [link](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/1606) to get the direction to which camera is facing.

[Here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OzRrqe) is the working example for your code.

```
if(keyboard[87]){ // W key
      var matrix = new THREE.Matrix4();
      matrix.extractRotation( mesh.matrix );
      let axis = new THREE.Vector3(0,0,-1);
      axis = matrix.multiplyVector3(axis);
      camera.translateOnAxis(axis,player.speed);
      }
if(keyboard[83]){ // S key
      var matrix = new THREE.Matrix4();
      matrix.extractRotation( mesh.matrix );
      let axis = new THREE.Vector3(0,0,1);
      axis = matrix.multiplyVector3(axis);
      camera.translateOnAxis(axis,player.speed);
}
if(keyboard[65]){ // A key
      var matrix = new THREE.Matrix4();
      matrix.extractRotation( mesh.matrix );
      let axis = new THREE.Vector3(-1,0,0);
      axis = matrix.multiplyVector3(axis);
      camera.translateOnAxis(axis,player.speed);
}
if(keyboard[68]){ // D key
      var matrix = new THREE.Matrix4();
      matrix.extractRotation( mesh.matrix );
      let axis = new THREE.Vector3(1,0,0);
      axis = matrix.multiplyVector3(axis);
      camera.translateOnAxis(axis,player.speed);
}

if(keyboard[37]){ // left arrow key
    camera.rotation.y -= player.turnSpeed;
}
if(keyboard[39]){ // right arrow key
    camera.rotation.y += player.turnSpeed;
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48030611/three-js-how-to-make-a-camera-follow-a-terrain-heightmap Please help me with my next question